# How can we generate oauth2.0 token in mule application dynamically without using postman?

Tags: mule, mule-esb

Is there any other way to generate the oauth2.0 token in mule soft it self?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should check out the [docs](https://docs.mulesoft.com/connectors/http/http-authentication) on configuring authentication on an HTTP requester. This covers the different OAuth 2 supported configurations.

Comment: Though it covers different authentications i just want to integrate the oauth 2.0 authentication in my service which generates the authentication code in my application rather than using postman or any other external tools.